# method that uses data retrieved from an observable on its own component returns undefined when used as Input()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a template `example.component.html` that receives a method as a variable to its click action:

```
<div>
  <button (click)="method()">click here</button>
</div>
```

on the `example.component.ts` file, the method comes from an input(), so I can use this template on multiple situations:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
    export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() method;
    
      constructor() {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

Here's where it gets complicated. At the parent component, the method that will be triggered on click uses a variable coming from an observable:

`parent-example.component.html`

```
  <example [method]="onClick"></example>
```

`parent-example.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-example',
  templateUrl: './parent-example.component.html',
})
export class ParentExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() method;
  business;

  constructor(businessEntityService: BusinessEntityService) {
    businessEntityService.entities$.subscribe(
      data => (this.business = data),
    );
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.business);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Even though the parent component is subscribing `businessEntityService` observable and I've check it has in fact data, when I click the button, the console logs `undefined`.

I understand this probably has to do with scope and the stack is looking for `this.business` at the children component, however I would love to know if there's anyway to call a method that uses a variable from a subscription from its own component as Input().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` context is being lost (I think). Can happen when passing class methods as params

Replace the `ParentExampleComponent#onClick` method with:

```js
onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.business);
}
```

**Note:** behind the scenes, Typescript will now treat `onClick` as a class property, and moves that code into the constructor. Using an arrow function locks the `this` context of that function